# XML getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, xml, alert

I have this function:

```
function worker(iS) {
    var office = docXML.getElementsByTagName("office")[iS];
    var counter = office.getElementsByTagName("worker").length;
    for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        return office.getElementsByTagName("worker")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }  
}
```

Note: on my docXML I have various "office"

```
<office>
    <workers>
        <worker>PersonA</worker>
        <worker>PersonB</worker>
    </workers>
</office>
<office>
    ...
</office>
...
```

In this case, counter=2. 
I am testing via alert(worker(1)) and shows me only PersonA. What can I do to appear on the alert PersonA and PersonB?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having "person A" and "person B" using your code. And, in your example, it should be `worker(0)`.

Comment: Do you understand what the `return` statement does inside loops? It _exits the function_. So why do you even have the loop if it’s never going to behave like a loop?

Comment: you break the loop by `return`. Need to build an array and return that after loop is done

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yeah, I think my code is correct. But it's strange that my alert only appears PersonA

Comment: Forget what I said, I'm sleeping. I was getting only "Person A". To get both person A and B, as Xufox and charlietfl said, put the `return` outside the for loop, as here: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/k30b9ar0/1/

Comment: Yeah I forgot that return break the loop, thanks Xufox, charlietfl and Gerardo Furtado ;)

Answer (score 0):

The return inside the for loop breaks the loop. Move it outside of the for loop and you are good to go.